# sql server execute command in multiple server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have several link server on my server (about 20 servers). on these server exists a similar database and I want to execute a stored procedure on these server in depend of a parameter on my stored procedure on my server. I have following query for this idea.

```
Create procedure test
    (
       @ServerName VarChar(100),
       @Code int
    )
As
    IF(@ServerName = 'Server1')Begin
       Exec Server1.SGDB.dbo.DocInsert @Code
    End Else IF(@ServerName = 'Server2')Begin
       Exec Server2.SGDB.dbo.DocInsert @Code
    End Else IF(@ServerName = 'Server3')Begin
       Exec Server3.SGDB.dbo.DocInsert @Code
    .
    .
    .
    End Else IF(@ServerName = 'Server20')Begin
       Exec Server20.SGDB.dbo.DocInsert @Code
    End
End
```

Can I have a dynamic query with `@ServerName` parameter without using exec(string command).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the body of your stored procedure with this dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = N'Exec ' + @ServerName + N'.SGDB.dbo.DocInsert @Code'

exec sp_executesql  @stmt = @sql, @params = N'@Code int', @Code = @Code
```

It will be also better to declare the parameter `@ServerName` as `NVarChar(128)` to always work on Unicode characters and to allow for the maximum length of a linked server name.